# Can I store a string in character array but reverse order, such that 0(index) points to last character in string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, reverse

I started to learn to program and I'm trying to store a string into a character array but in reverse order, such that array index position 0(zero) points to the last character in the string. I tried using for loops in different terms but getting the desired output. I want to solve this problem in C++.
Here is the code that I'm stuck on,

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     char str[maxn];
     string entstr;

     cin>>entstr;

     int len = entstr.length();
     cout<<len<<endl;

     for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)        //this makes \n no sense//
         for(int j = len-1 ; j >= 0 ; j--)
             str[i] = entstr[j];


     for(int i = len-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
         cout<<"Straight for array "<<i<<" "<<str[i]<<endl;        
            

    return 0;
}
```

```
OUTPUT:
sachin
6
Straight for array 5 s
Straight for array 4 s
Straight for array 3 s
Straight for array 2 s
Straight for array 1 s
Straight for array 0 s
```

Comment: Why do you have a second `for` loop? As Mr. Spock would say: this is highly illogical. For example, when `i` is 0 as a result of the inner for loop first you'll set `str[0]` to `entstr[len-1]`, then immediately after that you'll seto `str[0]` to `entstr[len-2]`, and so on. What do you intend to accomplish, by doing that?

Comment: *"I want to solve this problem in C++"* - it's already been solved. A `std::string` and the reverse iterators `rbegin()` and `rend()` do what seems exactly what you want.

Comment: `std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());` or `s = string(s.rbegin(), s.rend());`

Comment: Appreciate your reply, yes that second for loop is making no sense, and I'm trying different variations of for loop but not updating here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't wanna use `std::reverse` mentioned in the comments because you want to practice your algorithmic skills.

You can help yourself with this short program. It uses `std::malloc` to allocate a `char` array of the size of the input string. Then, you just need to loop backward through the character of the string and store it into your array.
I recommend you to follow (write it down on a paper) the values of `i` and `len-1-i` inside the loop. It will help you to understand how index works.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string entstr;
    cin >> entstr;

    int len = entstr.length();
    char* charArray = (char*) malloc (len);
     
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        charArray[i] = entstr[len-1-i];
    }
    
    cout << "charArray contains: ";
    for(int j = 0; j < len; j++)
    {
        cout << charArray[j];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Here, says avoid comment like thanks, but Thanks, I got what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any use for two loops. Just start the string from the front and your array from len-1 (just the way you did in the for loop for printing). You can take whatever length you want your char array to be.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     char str[100]; //put whatever you want the length of the char array to be
     string entstr;

     cin>>entstr;

     int len = entstr.length();
     cout<<len<<endl;

     for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
     {
         str[len-1-i]=entstr[i];
     }


     for(int i = len-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
         cout<<"Straight for array "<<i<<" "<<str[i]<<endl;        
            

    return 0;
}
```

You can use two pointers too for the same i.e. one starting from the front and one from the end (if you get confused)

```
 for(int i = 0, j=len-1 ; i < len ; i++, j--)
 {
     str[j]=entstr[i];
 }
```